# FOREACH LOOP Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "dbGetQuery""

Tags: mysql, r, foreach, doparallel

I am well practiced at simple implementations in R, however I am new to communicating to SQL through R and also parallel programming (no prior experience of these two things before today). I have written the below code with prompts from blogs, forums etc.

```
library(doParallel) 

library(RMySQL) 

library(DBI)

library(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster(12)

registerDoParallel(cl)

Postcodecsv <- read.csv("C:/Users/Henry Crosby/Desktop/PostcodeLatLong.csv")

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='****', password="******* ****", 

dbname='population_distance', host='****.**.*.*')

dbListFields(mydb,'Postcodes')

foreach (a = 1:120000, .combine="rbind") %dopar% {

  Done <- dbGetQuery(mydb, paste("select FID, Postcode2, (6371 * acos( cos( 
radians( ",Postcodecsv[a,6],"))*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(Longitude)-radians(",Postcodecsv[a,5],"))+sin(radians(",Postcodecsv[a,6],") )* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance from Postcodes having distance < 2 ORDER BY distance",sep=" "))

write.table(Done,file="C:/Users/Henry Crosby/Desktop/2km.csv",append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")

  }
```

This calculation works in a for loop but takes forever (I have to apply this to a LARGE dataset!). When I run the above code I get the error below! Can someone tell me why the error is coming and how I can work around it!

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "dbGetQuery""

Comment: I have found in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf that I must add .packages to the foreach when done in parallel. IE foreach (a = 1:120, .combine="rbind", .packages=c("DBI","RMySQL")). However I have a new error Error in { : task 1 failed - "Corrupt MySQL handle"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that foreach is auto-exporting the `mydb` object, but it doesn't work correctly because objects that contain socket connections can't be serialized and copied between processes.

I suggest that you initialize the cluster workers using the `clusterEvalQ` function to create `mydb` on each of the workers. You could try something like:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(RMySQL)
  mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='****', password="******* ****",
                    dbname='population_distance', host='****.**.*.*')
  NULL
})
```

However, you still need to prevent foreach from auto-exporting `mydb` by using the foreach `.noexport="mydb"` option. You can also use the foreach `.verbose=TRUE` option to verify what objects are being auto-exported to the workers.

Answer (score 0):

Why use R to handle the sql to csv migration? Consider a full SQL solution and leave processing on the database engine. Specifically, join the Postcodes table and PostcodeLatLong csv data (of course, import into MySQL database). Then use MySQL's [OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) facility. Altogether, you only have to run `dbGetQuery()` once without parallel looping:

```
expotCSV <- dbGetQuery("SELECT FID, Postcode2, (6371 * acos( cos( 
                     radians(Postcodecsv.col6))*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(Longitude)-
                     radians(Postcodecsv.col5))+sin(radians(Postcodecsv.col6))* sin(radians(latitude)))) 
                     AS distance     

              FROM Postcodes 
              INNER JOIN PostcodeLatLong ON csv.joinfield = PostcodeLatLong.joinfield
              HAVING distance < 2 
              ORDER BY distance

              INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/Henry Crosby/Desktop/2km.csv' 
              FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
              TERMINATED BY ';' 
              ESCAPED BY '\"' 
              LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n';")
```

The challenge is finding the `joinfield` or relationship between the two tables. However, SQL also allows [cartesian product or the cross join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) (for seemingly unrelated tables) where a query returns the total combination set between listed tables. You can use a where clause by some filtering clause:

```
FROM Postcodes, PostcodeLatLong 
WHERE Postcodes.somefactor = "..." AND PostcodeLatLong.somefactor = "..."
```

Alternatively, MySQL's `CROSS JOIN` (JOIN with no ON clause)

```
FROM Postcodes CROSS JOIN PostcodeLatLong 
WHERE Postcodes.somefactor = "..." AND PostcodeLatLong.somefactor = "..."
```